# Generate identical regular CSS class rules for pseudo class rules

Tags: css, webpack, sass

As an HTML element's pseudo classes ("pseudo states") cannot be triggered via JavaScript, I want to emulate pseudo-class CSS styling by creating identical CSS rules with regular classes, then use JavaScript to toggle these emulated pseudo classes:

```js
document.getElementById('action-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const underTest = document.getElementById('under-test');
  underTest.classList.contains('hover') ?
    underTest.classList.remove('hover') :
    underTest.classList.add('hover');
});
```

```css
button:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}

button.hover {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<button id="action-button">
  Regular button<br />
  Hover for seeing :hover pseudo class styling<br />
  Click for toggling emulated .hover class on "under test" button
</button>

<br />
<br />

<button id="under-test" class="hover">under test: Pseudo-class hover button</button>
```

This approach works for my purposes. Now I'm looking for a solution which generates such emulated CSS rules automatically from my SASS / `.scss` stylesheets:

For example, given this input **input.scss**:

```
span {
  a:focus {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

I'd like this output **output.css**:

```
span a:focus {
  color: red;
}

span a.focus {
  color: red;
}
```

or

```
span a:focus,
span a.focus {
  color: red;
}
```

Is there a SASS configuration or some Webpack plugin which automatically derives additional "emulated CSS rules" from all pseudo-class rules?

Comment: "HTML element's pseudo classes ("pseudo states") cannot be triggered via JavaScript" - well, they can, just indirectly: while they can't be triggered _specifically_, JS can modify the DOM such that the pseudo-classes are applied (e.g. checking a checkbox or radio for `:checked`, or setting `.disabled = true` for `:disabled`).

Comment: It can also be useful to use CSS variables (properties) which you can set in JS on the main element and can then be picked up by the pseudo element. e.g. el.setProperty('--color',  'blue') and in the CSS  ::before { color:  var(--color); }

Comment: @Dai, I don't see how one would do it for e.g. `:hover` or `:focus` (list of pseudo-classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes )

Comment: @Abdull use `input.focus()` for `:focus`. However, yes: `:hover` cannot be triggered by JS.

Comment: @Abdull How are you invoking `sass`? Are you running it directly from the command-line manually, or is it automated, e.g. as part of an `npm` action or other build process (e.g. Gulp, webpack, etc)?

Comment: Can you use PostCSS instead (or in addition to) SASS/SCSS?

Comment: You could create a simple mixin that would output both.